# How do I get rid of commas and periods, etc in R?

Tags: r

This is my data set:

```
    Depth.Fe
1    0,14.21
2    3,19.35
3   10,17.22
4   14,15.87
5   23,13.62
6   30,16.31
7   36,14.13
8   48,13.95
9      59,15
10  66,14.23
11  68,16.81
12  81,15.93
13  94,16.02
14  96,17.85
15 102,17.02
16 115,15.87
17 121,19.84
18 130,16.94
19 163,16.72
20  168,19.2
21 205,20.41
22 239,16.88
23 251,18.74
24 283,16.67
25 297,18.56
26 322,18.87
27 335,20.81
28 351,24.52
29 370,25.03
30 408,25.11
31 416,23.28
32 419,22.56
33    425,19
34 429,20.53
35 443,19.08
36 447,22.83
37 465,21.06
38 474,24.96
39 493,19.12
40 502,22.24
41 522,26.88
42 550,21.15
43 558,28.92
44 571,27.96
45 586,25.03
46 596,26.27
```

I want depth and Fe to be separated as individual columns, but nothing I try is working.
please help

Comment: If `,` is the delimiter, you could have used `sep=","` in the `read.csv`  with `skip=1`

Comment: Please always list what you've tried that isn't working. As it stands it looks like you've put _zero_ effort into helping yourself; SO is most receptive to those that appear to have been pulling on their own bootstraps.

Comment: As pointed out by @DavidArenburg, this can be resolved with `df2 <- read.csv(text = as.character(df1$Depth.Fe), header = FALSE); colnames(df2) <- c("Depth", Fe")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @akrun is definitely right in his comment to your post. If this is a dataset imported from somewhere, then follow his comment.

Assuming that somehow you were handed this weird dataset, I would try this:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$Depth.Fe,split=","))),nrow=2,byrow = T),stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df) <- c("Depth","Fe")
```

This would take a dataset that looks like this:

```
    Depth.Fe
1    0,14.21
2    3,19.35
```

to this:

```
    Depth    Fe
1       0 14.21
2       3 19.34
```